# How to copy an array or arraylist

Tags: java, arrays, arraylist, copy

Think there is an array named **barca[]**. The array have player list. Players are determined as class. For example **barca[0]=messi;** messi is a player class. I want to copy barca[]. If I write **barca2[]=barca[];** I copy the array but when barca2[] changes also barca[] changes. I want them independent. How can I do? 
`
public class Main {

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    Player barca[] = new Player[10];
    Player barca2[] = new Player[10];
    for(int i=0; i<10; i++){
        barca[i] = new Player();
        barca[i].id = i;
    }
    barca2 = barca;

    //print the arrays
    for(int i = 0; i<10; i++){
        System.out.print(barca[i].id);
    }
    System.out.println();
    for(int i = 0; i<10; i++){
        System.out.print(barca2[i].id);
    }

    //change an array
    barca2[5].id=100;
    System.out.println();   

    //print the arrays
    for(int i = 0; i<10; i++){
        System.out.print(barca[i].id);
    }
    System.out.println();
    for(int i = 0; i<10; i++){
        System.out.print(barca2[i].id);
    }

}
```

}

Output:

0123456789
0123456789
012341006789
012341006789
`

Comment: you should create two separate array or arraylist.

Comment: create two separate `ArrayList`

Comment: which type of array is `barca[]` and `barca2[]` is int, string or etc? can you plese provide code snippet?

Comment: barca2 is only another reference to the same array. create a new one and assign players to it.

Comment: barca[] is an array. barca2[] is another array. type of array is player(class player). if there is no solution on array, I can try it on arraylist. You can think same question on arraylist. barca and barca2 are arraylist...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is simple to implement, if we go by Arraylist then also we get two options as listed, direct and indirect , in sample code. You may edit the object after copying the arraylist. It wouldn't affect the first arraylist. Please check full code for complete understanding.

```
//1. Direct: Copy player list into player1 List
List<Player> player1 = new ArrayList<Player>(player);

//2. Indirect using method: Copy player list into player1 List
List<Player> player1 = new ArrayList<Player>();
player1.addAll(player);
```

You may see the complete code [here](https://gist.github.com/MaheshKapoor/1e74e2263a765ba62d1d).
You may test the code [here](http://ideone.com/feA6v3).

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
List<String>baraca=new ArrayList<>();
        List<String>temp=new ArrayList<>();

        baraca.add("messi 1");
        baraca.add("messi 2");
        baraca.add("messi 3");
        baraca.add("messi 4");
        temp= new ArrayList<String>(baraca);

        temp.add("messi temp");

        System.out.println(baraca);
        System.out.println(temp);
```

Output:

```
[messi 1, messi 2, messi 3, messi 4]
[messi 1, messi 2, messi 3, messi 4, messi temp]
```